# Image Captcha Refresh not displaying refresh link

Tags: forms, captcha

I want to add button/link for refreshing Image Captcha, therefore I've installed and enabled [Image Captcha Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_captcha_refresh) module. But this module is doing nothing, no refresh button is added, no options are added to Image Captcha settings page, no javascript is loaded from this module.

My captcha is in custom form:

```
$form['captcha'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Code',
    '#type' => 'captcha',
    '#captcha_type' => 'image_captcha/Image',
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried recreating your problem and i saw that after you enable the refresh module for the image recaptcha, a link is added below the image in all the forms where captcha is enabled.

But there is no configuration page specific to this refresh module. The link works fine in reloading the image.

I suggest that you add your form via configuration page of the captcha module instead of adding it in the code.

just include your form machine name and captcha in the captcha module configuration page.

Comment: Probably you're right that it is not possible to add image captcha refresh link when captcha field is added directly in hook_form(); I will test it when I have time for this.